# extract a zip file with a windows shortcut using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

I'm trying to extract a zip file using a Windows shortcut both the zip file and the shortcut are in the same folder I've tried to use Powershell to extract the zip file. I want to use PowerShell as the directory will be unknown.

I've used this PowerShell command in the target of the shortcut.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command "$shortcutPath = Split-Path -Path $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition) -Parent; Expand-Archive -Path `"$shortcutPath\file.zip`" -DestinationPath `"$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Extracted`""
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

I was hoping for the zip file to be unzipped and for it to be placed on the desktop and for the new file to be called Extracted.

Comment: The PowerShell CLI requires embedded `"` chars. to be escaped as ``\"``, not as `\`"`

Comment: That said, your command doesn't actually need embedded `"` chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the zip file is in the same location as your shortcut then why try to get the `$shortcut` path? You can just use a relative path passing the zip name as your argument:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -NoProfile -Command "Expand-Archive file.zip -DestinationPath $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Extracted"
```

Just make sure that your shortcut's `Start in` argument is left blank so the path is always relative:

[image: something]

Comment: yess omg its soo simple thank you I definitely overthought this proses

Comment: @phil well now you learnt something new so thats good ;)